# Solr range queries against a TrieDoubleField behave unexpectedly with negative values?

Tags: solr, search-engine, range

I have searched all of the overflow/exchange sites and pored over Google for hours to no avail, so I hope someone is a Solr genius and can tell me where I'm going wrong.

We are in a transition between a previous search server and Solr, which requires that we store our geo data in separate latitude and longitude fields for the time being. I have defined the fields using the `solr.TrieDoubleField` as recommended by numerous sources.

```
<fieldType name="tdouble" class="solr.TrieDoubleField" precisionStep="8" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
<field name="latitude_1" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" required="false" />
<field name="longitude_1" type="tdouble" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="false" required="false" />
```

The issue that I am having is that range queries against the longitude value (which is predominantly less than zero) don't work at all. Strangely, the ranges work if I enter the query values as positive numbers, but that doesn't inspire confidence.

Here is an example query:

```
longitude_1:[-95 TO -94]
```

This returns no results. However, if I query with positive numbers, like so:

```
longitude_1:[94 TO 95]
```

I get these results (I used `fl=longitude_1` for brevity):

```
<doc>
  <str name="longitude_1">-94.60046</str>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="longitude_1">-94.03403</str>
</doc>
<doc>
  <str name="longitude_1">-94.03403</str>
</doc>
```

I noticed that the values are displayed in `<str>` tags, but I am assuming that this is a string output representation of the internal `TrieDoubleField`. If that is not the case, perhaps something else is wrong in my schema or Solr configuration.

Answer (score 0):

The minus sign probably gets interpreted as a query operator (meaning that the clause is prohibited). You should try to [escape](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Escaping%20Special%20Characters) it (with a backslash).